# Excel formula to return value from grid

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have some data that looks something like this

```
A B C D E F G
B C D E F G A
C D E F G A B
D E F G A B C 
E F G A B C D
F G A B C D E 
G A B C D E F
```

In addition, I have a piece of data that looks like this:

```
A 
B
```

What I need to lookup is the row header for the row where the top value resides, when the column header is the bottom value. For instance, in this example, I would look in the first row to find `B`, then I would look down the column until I found `A`, then I would look at the row header to return `G`

```
 A  (B) C D E F G
 B   C  D E F G A
 C   D  E F G A B
 D   E  F G A B C 
 E   F  G A B C D
 F   G  A B C D E 
(G) (A) B C D E F
```

I've tried using `HLOOKUP`, `INDEX`, `MATCH`, etc., but I keep running into a roadblock when I need to provide an array for the whole column.

Here's one such example of the syntax that's giving me errors:

```
=CONCAT(address(8,1):address(12,1))
```

I can't have the `:` between my two cell addresses.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the 1st row in your example the actual column labels, or the header row of a table at some random location?

Comment: Should that : be ,":",

Comment: @fixer1234 it's both :3 It's kind of a header, in that it's the reference for the rest of the columns, but it can also be the data (For example, if my data set was A A then it would return A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this, but here's a quick and dirty solution.

[image]

I stuck your grid in an arbitrary location (B2:H8).  J2 and J3 are your lookup values and the result is in J4.  What is in column L is components of the answer for the purposes of explanation because the formula gets long.

The first piece is in L3, finding the `B` target in the top row:

```
=MATCH(J3,B2:H2,0)
```

It finds the target `B` in column 2 of the array, and this is used in the next step of finding A in that column.  L2 contains:

```
=MATCH(J2,OFFSET(B2,0,L3-1,7,1),0)
```

OFFSET is anchored to the top left corner of the array (B2).  The column that `B` was found in was the second column of the array, but that is an offset of 1 from the first column, hence the `-1` (I love it when I get to use "hence" in a sentence).  OFFSET lets you specify a range using height and width parameters.  The `7` is the array height in this example.

MATCH finds the target `A` in row 7 of that column of the array.

Now you just need to go to that row of the first column of the array:

```
=INDEX(B2:B8,L2,0)
```

There, you find your answer: `G`

You can substitute the component formulas for the components to get a self-contained, stand-alone formula:

```
=INDEX(B2:B8,MATCH(J2,OFFSET(B2,0,MATCH(J3,B2:H2,0)-1,7,1),0),0)
```